# Rails 4.2 connect to old legacy Mysql DB - Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mysql2

After hours of googleing, trying this and that, I'm wondering if anyone here has any suggestions on how to overcome this error.

First, I am dealing with a very old MySQL v3.23.58 DB/Server which at this time I can't upgrade.  A migration from this db is in the works, but I have need to access it via a Rails UI at the moment.  So the error I get below appears to be an incompatibility with the initial connection string sent setting some sessions variables, yes?  I can connect to the remote DD/Server using the *nix command line mysql-client and perform queries.   I've tried changing the init values via the connection definition, no success..  I'm considering alternative options to send data from remote server to the local rails DB and query the local DB remotely.  But I'd, at this juncture, prefer to read/write directly to the remote DB.  Any assistance would be appreciated!

Thank you

```
td@noc:~/rails_workspace/SC$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.2.1 :001 > ServerBan
 => ServerBan (call 'ServerBan.connection' to establish a connection) 
2.2.1 :002 > b = ServerBan.first()
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'NAMES latin1,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = '', @@SESSION.strict = 0, @@SESSION.sql_auto' at line 1
```

### ./config/database.yml

```
server1:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  host: <ip>
  port: 3306
  username: <user>
  password: <passwd>
  database: monitor
  strict: false
  variables: 
    sql_mode: ''
```

### ./app/models/serverban.rb

```
class ServerBan < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :server1
    self.table_name='rules'
end
```

Comment: Is the indenting of `sql_mode: ''` and `strict: false` in line with the other entries? Seems like these two lines are indented one more level.

Comment: 'variables' is indented 2 spaces from left, sql_mode and strict are indented 4 space from left.  What I thought I saw was that these were relative to the variables branch

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `./config/database.yml` file as follows:

```
server1:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  host: <ip>
  port: 3306
  username: <user>
  password: <passwd>
  database: monitor
  strict: false
  variables: 
    sql_mode: ''
```

Only `sql_mode` should be under the variables section. `strict` will be part of the main params.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html for an explanation of each of these params, including the `variables` param.

Comment: I modified the sequence, no love... I had reviewed the link you referenced before posting and that's what lead me to the variables and mode settings.  The MySQL site documentation states:   Beginning with MySQL 4.1, you can change the SQL mode at runtime....
You can retrieve the current global or session sql_mode value with the following statements:

SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
This mode changes syntax and behavior to conform more closely to standard SQL, and is available beginning in MySQL 4.1.1.

Comment: So I somehow need to prevent these from being sent on the connection init.